# generating random number between 1, 16

Tags: c#, random

Hi everyone I have two dimensional array 4*4. I have to fill it with numbers from 1 to 16 inclusive and randomly. Each number should be used only once and all the numbers between 1-16 should be used. I have written the following code, but for some reason that I don't know some items in the array are not filled !!
can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
    public void generateRandState()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int temp ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                temp = rnd.Next(1, 17);
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
                if (taken[temp] == false)
                {
                    state[i, j] = temp;
                    taken[temp] = true;
                }
                else // for repeated rands
                {
                    temp = rnd.Next(1, 17);
                    Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    while (!flag)
                    {
                        if (taken[temp] == false)
                        {
                            flag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            temp = rnd.Next(1, 17);
                        Console.WriteLine(temp);
                    }
                    if (taken[temp] == false)
                    {
                        state[i, j] = temp;
                        taken[temp] = true;

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll probably need to set `flag` to false before the `while` statement

Comment: You'll learn far more by learning to use your debugger and stepping through your code.

Comment: @LeeTaylor if I set it to true it will use the same number more than once which is not allowed

Comment: No, the first time your while loop will run, after that it will **never** run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `while (!flag)` with `while (true)`.  The `break` will already get you out of the `while` statement.  The `flag` variable is completely unnecessary.

Your algorithm is pretty inefficient.  As dasblinkenlight points out, there's better ways to accomplish what you are doing.

You should also know that `taken` would need to be cleared if you ever call `generateRandState` more than once.

Answer (score 4):

> Each number should be used only once and all the numbers between 1-16 should be used.

This is called a *random shuffle*. You can use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to build it.

[This post](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) provides the code for it.

```
static Random _random = new Random();
public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array) {
var random = _random;
for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--) {
    int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
    T tmp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i - 1];
    array[i - 1] = tmp;
}
}
```

Comment: I have a question, if I call this function multiple times will it produce the same output everytime??

Comment: @Alaa You can have it both ways, depending on your needs. Since `Random` is actually a pseudo-random generator, you could make it produce the same sequence again by supplying it with the same seed value. If you do not want to see the same permutation, seed the random number generator with a different seed. You could still get the same arrangement by incident because there's a finite number of them, but the probability of it would be really low.

Comment: @Alaa Generally, yes, because your code may take a while to discover the few non-taken spots in the `taken[]` array. When you have 16 items, it does not matter much, because we're talking differences in microseconds. If you venture into, say, a 25x25 grid, the shuffle will be significantly faster.